# Recommendation for LayoutManager

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have three components that need to be laid out vertically so that the top component takes 30% of
the available height of the window, the middle one takes 20%, and the bottom one takes the rest of it.

As the window is resized, so will they, but their height relative to the window should remain the same.

Which layout manager should I use to implement this?

Comment: Note that GridBagLayout `weightx/weighty` only distributes the **extra** available space (it will first give to each component its "preferredSize", if possible). So unless you force the preferred size of those components to be (0x0), `GridBagLayout` will not achieve exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and find which suits best for your requirements (or more than one - you can use more than one layout manager).

I would recommend `GridBagLayout`. It has a lot of "fine tunings". `weigthy` is the field of `GridBagConstraints` of your interest - it manages how the space will be distributed to elements in vertical when resized.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with a standard layout manager, consult the [visual guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). `GridBagLayout` is your best bet, I think.

I myself would probably use [miglayout](http://www.miglayout.com) for the increased maintainability.

Both of these divide your panel in a grid. You can then assign resize weights to the columns and rows.

Answer (score 2):

`Box layout` set to Y Axis OR `Grid bag layout`.

In gridbag layout you can set the "weight" anyway. That is the one which is going to help you in 30%. 10% thing

Comment: Thanks. I tried BoxLayout, but the problem I had with it is it sets all components to equal heights.

Comment: @TomTucker: Then, you need to move with GridBag Layout. There you can do what you need, with 'weight' option.